# Can I use PropertyResourceConfigurer's setOrder method to override another PropertyResourceConfigurer's properties?

Tags: spring

I understand `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer` implements `org.springframework.core.Ordered`. See [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyResourceConfigurer.html#setOrder-int-)  for `setOrder` method.

I am not sure how one can use the `setOrder` method for `PropertyResourceConfigurer` though.

Can I use `setOrder` for one `PropertyResourceConfigurer` to override properties from another `PropertyResourceConfigurer`? If `setOrder` is not meant to be used that way, then can someone please give me a practical use case for this method in the context of `PropertyResourceConfigurer`?

**edit 1**: Here are my PropertySourcesPlaceholderconfigurers:

```
@Configuration
public class PropertyConfigurerConfiguration {

    static class defaultConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() throws IOException {
            PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
            propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(Boolean.TRUE);
            propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setOrder(35);
            propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocations(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath*:META-INF/props/*.properties"));
            return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
        }
    }

    @Profile(Profiles.DEV)
    static class devConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() throws IOException {
            PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
            propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(Boolean.TRUE);
            propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setOrder(25);
            propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocations(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath*:META-INF/props/dev/*.properties"));
            return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
        }
 ...
```

And here is how I activate the profile: `spring.profiles.active="dev"`

**edit 2**:

Reading one of your comments about the bean IDs, I modified my code as follows:

```
@Profile(Profiles.DEV)
    static class devConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer devPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() throws IOException {//Now called devProperXXX
```

and it appears it now works...

Can someone please explain to me why changing bean IDs would change the behavior? **Is this documented somewhere?** If so where?

Comment: You mean the abstract class `PropertyResourceConfigurer` or one of its concrete implementations, like `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`?

Comment: Also, I don't think you override one instance of `PropertyResourceConfigurer` (or concrete implementations) just by using `Ordered`. `Ordered` is for setting an order in which a list of post processors is applied, if you want this to be in a certain order. If you have two `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurers` they will be applied in the order you specify, but both will coexist.

Comment: Thanks. I actually meant properties from one configurer would override properties from another configurer. That's what my question referred to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully, I understood this correctly. Short answer is "yes".
If you have two beans defined like

```
<bean id="mappings"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="properties">
            <value>
                p1=v1
                p2=v2
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="order" value="25" />
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    </bean>

<bean id="mappings2" 
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="properties">
            <value>
                p1=v111
                p3=v3
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="order" value="35" />
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

"p1" property's value will be "v1" because the order of its `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` is lower (and thus of higher precedence).

A scenario where I can see this useful is with .jars that have their own configurers and their own `.properties` files. If these jars are searched for .xml configuration files (in `classpath*:*.xml` kind of style) I think one can override a property from one of the xml files by defining another propertyplaceholderconfigurer with a lower order value (by default the order is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`).

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll try what you advised and reply here accordingly.

Comment: I have tried as advised unfortunately properties are not "merged" as required... So you either get p1 and p2 (if mappings is picked up) or p1 and p3 (if mappings2 is picked up).... :-(

Comment: How is your scenario configured? Where is the first PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and where is the second?

Comment: Also, what bean IDs do these two configurers have?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Please bear with me. I will edit my post when I have access to my source code.

Comment: Hello Andrei. I have edited my post as requested. I forgot to mention another of my requirements: I must use profiles: each overriding bean will be bound to a profile: dev, test, etc...

Comment: Andrei: I changed the name of the bean method and it now works. I have edited my post: can you please kindly point me to relevant documentation about how changing bean IDs changes the way they override one another?

Comment: When you had two beans with same ID it was overriding, one bean definition was replacing the other. With different IDs you end up with two beans that both are loaded and their properties are merged. In case of duplicate properties, the order is of essence.

Comment: This is just like with .xml configuration files: if you have one .xml where you define a bean with a name and in the same .xml you `<import resource />` another .xml with another bean with the same id as the first one then, depending where `<import resource />` is placed in the .xml one bean definition will override the other or vice-versa. With .xml files is all about the order in which bean definitions are placed in the file(s) (I said files because you have one `<import resource />`)

Comment: Thanks very much for your help!! It is now much clearer to me how to configure my beans.